# Programmatically check an ag-grid checkbox

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm using browser automation software to run automated UI tests.  Our front end site uses Vue and ag-grid.  My browser automation software essentially allows us to use typical javascript/jquery selectors to interact w/ the UI automatically.

I'm trying to get our browser automation software to check boxes in an ag-grid checkbox, inside an ag-grid.

[image]

I am not a Vue developer, so I was trying the typical things I'd do.  Things like:

```
$('.ag-selection-checkbox').click();
```

But nothing I do actually clicks and selects to box.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE For those in my situation.  I used the ag API like so:

```
document.querySelector('#myGrid').__vue__
   .gridOptions.api.forEachNode((row,index) => {
       document.querySelector('#myGrid').__vue__.
           gridOptions.api.getRowNode(row.id).selectThisNode(true); 
       }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the class that is directly associated with the checkbox, in this case it would be the class applied to the input element: `ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input`.

You can get the checkbox of the first row like this:

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector('.ag-center-cols-viewport .ag-row .ag-checkbox-input');
checkbox.click();
```

Please see [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mN7iD4a5BgBMWBjQ) showcasing a row selection via the DOM based on the button click.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to eventually use this instead, but I think it's because of the above instead, but I think it's because I'm loading from the server, and this would have worked otherwise.

Comment: No worries :) Glad you solved it.
The class .ag-selection-checkbox I think is the culprit here, if you inspect the DOM, you can see that has a margin of 12px. Perhaps the click event was focused on the margin and not the checkbox, hence using the .ag-checkbox-input ensured that the checkbox was directly selected.